# Stand alone GPU or integrated Intel graphics

Tags: graphics

I'm running 13.10 on a desktop with Core 2 Duo 3.0GHz/ 7GB RAM.

Will I get a performance advantage if I use a GeForce GT 630 GPU instead of the Intel Corp. 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The [GeForce](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce%20GT%20630M) with a Average G3D Mark of 751 will run faster and consume more power, an issue if you run on battery. Should you, indeed, be on a notebook PC on battery, you may wish to extend battery runtime by choosing the Intel integrated GPU instead which has a [G3D Mark of 60](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/video_lookup.php?gpu=Intel%20G41%20Express%20Chipset&id=940).

Comment: I should have mentioned. It's a desktop so battery life is not an issue.